# Crystal Report data on multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm crystal reports v 13.0.0.2

I display data in this report like this:

```
private ReportDocument dispatchNote;
string connectionstring = UserDatabase.getConnectionString();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            //Get sql
            string sqlstatement = getSqlStatement();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstatement))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_No", Order_No);
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        dispatchNote.SetDataSource(dt);
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = dispatchNote;




                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        sda.Dispose();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The parameter I pass is Order_No and show the results on the report.

I want to pass a list of parameters one by one to this query and then display the results on separate pages in Crystal Reports. Passing the parameters and looping is not the problem.  How to display the first result in first page, second result in second page and so on in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result will be prompt using "Details" section, I do suppose.

Go to `Section Expert` choose the section you intend to set, then `Paging` and then `New Page After`

Comment: Thank you Emanuele for your reply. I was able to sort this out using groups. I grouped the report using Order number and it did the trick. However, I face another problem now. I'm using a formula in this report but it should calculate only on the basis of values in the current page of the report.  I'm using sum of prices but it calculates sum of prices of all the entries. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Use Running Total Field, and then set as Reset Condition the field you're grouping on